# Oracle version of the Sql Server "sqlcmd.exe" tool to deploy .sql scripts

Tags: oracle, command-line

Microsoft Sql Server has a command line tool called sqlcmd.exe.

You can use it to deploy .sql scripts.

I have googled and binged and found many Oracle command line tools, but I have yet to find one that will deploy a sql package.

Here is a simple example:

```
sqlcmd.exe -i .\MySqlScript.sql -S "MySqlServerMachine\MyInstancenName"  -E -o ".\MyOutputLogFileName.txt"
```

The command line will run the file "MySqlScript.sql" against a Sql Server (Instance) named "MySqlServerMachine\MyInstancenName" using integrated security ("-E") and output the results to a file named  "MyOutputLogFileName.txt".

Is there a Oracle version of this tool?

---

I found `oradim`, but it is unclea if it runs a .sql script.

---

Based on parado's response, I found the below URL:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#CJAGIECA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a Sql*Plus:

```
sqlplus user/pass@connect @scriptname
```

If you want output file, add to your script:

```
spool log.out
```

Comment: A [link to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/toc.htm) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I found this documentation.  I have upvoted your response.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#CJAGIECA